# how do you encode a NULL char (\000) into NSData?

Tags: objective-c, ios, null, nsdata

how do you encode a NULL char (\000) into NSData ? I cannot fathom how to do this. I ultimately want this to be part of a larger data string that I construct, but I can't figure out how to bring it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
unsigned char zeroByte = 0;
[data appendBytes:&zeroByte length:1];
```